# Problems deploying a Wordpress Docker image in AWS via ECR and ECS (Serverless & Static)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I am relatively new to AWS and I want to deploy a simple Wordpress Docker image in AWS via ECR and ECS as a serverless website. Unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Specifically, I have a Wordpress image from the DockerHub with the commands:

1. docker pull wordpress:latest
2. docker tag wordpress:latest [ECR-Repository-URI]
3. docker push [ECR-Repository-URI]
   in an AWS ECR repository via the console.

This image is displayed to me with ~300MB in ECR.
Now I want to use the whole thing via AWS ECS (Fargate) in combination with a LoadBalancer.

Unfortunately, I am not able to create the service for ECS because I get errors when creating the service.

Specifically, I get these two error messages:

1. error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: [RequestToken] HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
2. ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount587080174/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

I would be very happy if anyone can help me with this problem.

Many thanks in advance

After a complete reset of the project, I keep getting the same error messages.